# Нужно написать код с использованием цикла for(должен быть максимум один цикл фор) на с++

Tags: c++

Задание звучит так: S = (2i+1)!
дошел только до таких размышлений, факториал числа могу посчитать, а вот от скобки проблематично

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, b = 1, c = 0;
    cout << "Введите n: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        b *= i;
        c += (2*i + 1)*b;
    }
    cout << "Cумма = "  << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: Задание уточните

Comment: найти значение суммы s=(2*i+1)!(факториал)

Comment: как я понял, при подставлении любого i прога должна считать факториалы нечет чисел по формуле

Comment: Попробуйте узнать, во сколько раз слагаемое на `k`-ой итерации отличается от `k-1`. Отдельно считайте слагаемое и сумму.

Comment: не понял ваше объяснение:(

Answer (score 2):

Чем i-слагаемое отличается от прошлого? Двумя новыми множителями

```
s = 0;
m = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    m *= (2*i) * (2*i + 1);
    s += m;
}
```

Comment: ```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int m,n = 1, s = 0;
    cout << "Введите n: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    m *= (2*i) * (2*i + 1);
    s += m;
    }
    cout << "Cумма = "  << s << endl;

}
```

Comment: выводит какое то большое число...

Comment: Спасибо, понял как решается!

Comment: @Гена https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer